# How to build an install profile progmatically

Tags: 7, features, distributions

I need to create an install profile from an existing site. My question is what to do with the site configurations? The site is pretty complex, so putting them manually in the profile is out of the question.

My current best idea is to create features from the site, and revert them during the install, but it has a big drawback: If I have to modify something on a site that is installed this way, the state of the features will be "overridden", so they need to be ignored or recreated.

I've checked out some possible solutions, but none of them seemed to be perfect.

- [Ftools](http://drupal.org/project/ftools) can "detach" features, but only for a few types of settings.
- [Profiler](http://drupal.org/project/profiler) seems to be exactly what I need, but it also lacks of support for most of the settings.
- With [Features Override](http://drupal.org/project/features_override) I can override the install profile's own features, but is it a good practice? I'm afraid it could cause problems when the complexity increases.
- I've heard about [Ctools Export Bonus](http://drupal.org/project/drush_ctex_bonus), but only 600 people downloaded it yet. Is it safe to use?

So wich is the best (or the least worst) solution currently, with drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

The questions you are asking are pretty hard to crack. We have build [Kraftwagen](http://kraftwagen.org) which is a Drush extension and a bunch of Drupal modules that will fit your needs.

Please have a look and let us know if it worked for you.